# Parsing data with e.parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm receiving the data from the JavaScript client in the format of:

```golang
type ContactDetails struct {
    Email   string
    Subject string
    Message string
    Color1  []string
    Color2  []string
}
```

The data had been sent from the `PostForm` as:

```sh
Post from website! r.PostFrom = map[color1:[my color 1 - 1 my color 1 - 2] color2:[my color 2 - 1 my color 2 - 2] email:[my email] message:[my message] subject:[my subject]]
```

[image]

So, I thought the best way to handle it the Google Apps script is using `e.parameters` not `e.parameter`, pls correct me if this is wrong approach.

In my GAS web app, only first field in both `color1` and `color2` had been posted in the related spreadsheet columns, though I expected to see array of 2 elements in each.

[image]

Sure, "Result of the code" is what I see after executed the codes in the question, "Expected result" is what I was expecting the code in the question will give as an output. The "Targeted final result" is the final result I'm working to approach, I think if I fixed the code to give the "Expected result", then it should not be difficult to tune it to generate the final output as needed in the format of "Targeted final result"

My GAS script is:

```
function doPost(e){
  output = handleResponse(e)
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  var result, message;
  // Prevent concurrent access overwriting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(1000);  // wait 1 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairse it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameters = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var nextRow = lastRow + 1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    if(lastRow < 10){
      RefID = "PRF.00" + lastRow
    } else {
      if(lastRow < 100){
        RefID = "PRF.0" + lastRow
      } else {
        RefID = "PRF." + lastRow
      }
    }
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Ref"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(RefID);
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
         row.push(new Date());
        } else { // else use header name to get data
          row.push(e.parameters[headers[i]]);
       }
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // return json success results
    result = true;
    message = link;
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    result = false;
    message = e;
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
    var output = JSON.stringify({"result":result, "message": message});
  }
  return output;
}
```

I'm publishing my GAS a:

[image]

If info about my client side is required, here the details:
I'm using `GO` lang as below;

```golang
// go build -ldflags "-H=windowsgui"
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/zserge/lorca"
)

// ContactDetails ...
type ContactDetails struct {
    Email   string
    Subject string
    Message string
    Color1  []string
    Color2  []string
}

// ReturnedResult ...
type ReturnedResult struct {
    Result  bool   `json:"result"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("forms.html"))
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }

    r.ParseForm()

    details := ContactDetails{
        Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
        Subject: r.FormValue("subject"),
        Message: r.FormValue("message"),
        Color1:  r.Form["color1"], // as "color1" is array,
        Color2:  r.Form["color2"], // as "color2" is array,
    }
    fmt.Printf("Post from website! r.PostFrom = %v\n", r.PostForm)

    sheetID := "AKfycbxfMucXOzX15tfU4errRSAa9IzuTRbHzvUdRxzzeYnNA8Ynz8LJuBuaMA/exec"
    url := "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + sheetID + "/exec"
    bytesRepresentation, err := json.Marshal(details)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(bytesRepresentation))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // read all response body
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // close response body
    resp.Body.Close()

    webReturn := ReturnedResult{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &webReturn); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(webReturn.Message)

    //tmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{webReturn.Result})
    tmpl.Execute(w, webReturn)
}

func main() {
    // Start Host goroutine
    go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", index)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
    }()

    // Start UI
    ui, err := lorca.New("http://localhost:8090/index", "", 480, 320)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ui.Close()

    <-ui.Done()
}
```

With the `html` in the below template `forms.html`

```html
<title>Form Submittal</title>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label>Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject"><br />
    <label>Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />

    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="color1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="color2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="color1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="color2" /></td>
        </tr>
      <table>

   <input type="submit">
</form>
{{if .Result}}
    <div id='foo'>
        <a href={{.Message}}>Download PDF file</a>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
    <script>
        // setTimeout(function () {document.querySelector('#foo').style.display='none'}, 5000);
    </script>
{{end}}
```

The console output data is:

```sh
Post from website! r.PostFrom = map[color1:[my color 1 - 1 my color 1 - 2] color2:[my color 2 - 1 my color 2 - 2] email:[my email] message:[my message] subject:[my subject]]    
Details = {my email my subject my message [my color 1 - 1 my color 1 - 2] [my color 2 - 1 my color 2 - 2]}

bytesRepresentation = [123 34 69 109 97 105 108 34 58 34 109 121 32 101 109 97 105 108 34 44 34 83 117 98 106 101 99 116 34 58 34 109 121 32 115 117 98 106 101 99 116 34 44 34 77 101 115 115 97 103 101 34 58 34 109 121 32 109 101 115 115 97 103 101 34 44 34 67 111 108 111 114 49 34 58 91 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 49 32 45 32 49 34 44 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 49 32 45 32 50 34 93 44 34 67 111 108 111 114 50 34 58 91 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 50 32 45 32 49 34 44 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 50 32 45 32 50 34 93 125]
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the difference between "Result of the code", "Expected result" and "Targeted final result" in your image of sheet? And also, can you provide the sample value of `bytesRepresentation` of `bytesRepresentation, err := json.Marshal(details)`?

Comment: Sure @Tanaike , "Result of the code" is what I see after executed the codes in the question, "Expected result" is what I was expecting the code in the question will give as an output. The "Targeted final result" is the final result I'm working to approach, I think if I fixed the code to give the "Expected result", then it should not be difficult to tune it to generate the final output as needed in the format of "Targeted final result"

Comment: @Tanaike,  bytesRepresentation = [123 34 69 109 97 105 108 34 58 34 109 121 32 101 109 97 105 108 34 44 34 83 117 98 106 101 99 116 34 58 34 109 121 32 115 117 98 106 101 99 116 34 44 34 77 101 115 115 97 103 101 34 58 34 109 121 32 109 101 115 115 97 103 101 34 44 34 67 111 108 111 114 49 34 58 91 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 49 32 45 32 49 34 44 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 49 32 45 32 50 34 93 44 34 67 111 108 111 114 50 34 58 91 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 50 32 45 32 49 34 44 34 109 121 32 99 111 108 111 114 32 50 32 45 32 50 34 93 125]

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal of "Expected result", how about the following modification? In this case, please modify `handleResponse()` of your Google Apps Script as follows.

#### From:

```
row.push(e.parameters[headers[i]]);
```

#### To:

```
var temp = e.parameters[headers[i]];
row.push(Array.isArray(temp) ? temp.join(",") : temp);
// Or if you want to ensure empty objects are excluded from the .join(), you can use:
// row.push(Array.isArray(temp) ? (temp.filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0)).join(",") : temp);
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

Comment: Thanks, "Expected result" worked as expected, if I stuck with "Targeted result" will come back to you :)